# No Connection to GooglePlayServices from AVD

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am currently trying to access the GooglePlayServices from an API 23 AVD. However, every time I attempt to connect, the AVD responds that there is no internet connection.

I have asked for permission in my Android Manifest, and I believe have made a valid GoogleApiClient, so currently I am not quite sure what the problem is.

This is the result from the lolcat:

```
05-08 19:23:48.659 10937-10937/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
05-08 19:23:48.803 10937-10937/com.example.denny.protoype2 W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.denny.protoype2-1/lib/x86_64
05-08 19:23:48.861 10937-10937/com.example.denny.protoype2 I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up, version: 8487
05-08 19:23:48.861 10937-10937/com.example.denny.protoype2 I/GMPM: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.GMPM VERBOSE
05-08 19:23:48.865 10937-10937/com.example.denny.protoype2 E/GMPM: GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.
05-08 19:23:48.865 10937-10937/com.example.denny.protoype2 E/GMPM: Scheduler not set. Not logging error/warn.
05-08 19:23:48.950 10937-10964/com.example.denny.protoype2 E/GMPM: Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
05-08 19:23:49.088 10937-10968/com.example.denny.protoype2 D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
05-08 19:23:49.434 10937-10968/com.example.denny.protoype2 I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-08 19:23:49.606 10937-10968/com.example.denny.protoype2 W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-08 19:23:49.606 10937-10968/com.example.denny.protoype2 W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7fc8fab766c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
05-08 19:23:49.687 10937-10937/com.example.denny.protoype2 I/Choreographer: Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-08 19:25:07.546 10937-10968/com.example.denny.protoype2 W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-08 19:25:07.546 10937-10968/com.example.denny.protoype2 W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7fc8fcbf0740, error=EGL_SUCCESS
05-08 19:25:07.983 10937-10968/com.example.denny.protoype2 E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7fc8fed394d0
05-08 19:25:07.991 10937-10968/com.example.denny.protoype2 D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0x7fc8feeb2c00 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x7fc8fed0ba60
05-08 19:25:09.149 10937-12092/com.example.denny.protoype2 I/GMPM: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
05-08 19:25:10.042 10937-10937/com.example.denny.protoype2 W/ViewRootImpl: Cancelling event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_CANCEL, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=575.4968, y[0]=537.2461, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=818623, downTime=815709, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
05-08 19:25:10.042 10937-10937/com.example.denny.protoype2 W/ViewRootImpl: Cancelling event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_CANCEL, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=575.4968, y[0]=537.2461, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=818623, downTime=815709, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
05-08 19:25:10.042 10937-10937/com.example.denny.protoype2 W/ViewRootImpl: Cancelling event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_CANCEL, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=575.4968, y[0]=537.2461, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=818623, downTime=815709, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
05-08 19:25:10.042 10937-10937/com.example.denny.protoype2 W/ViewRootImpl: Cancelling event due to no window focus: MotionEvent { action=ACTION_CANCEL, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=575.4968, y[0]=537.2461, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=818623, downTime=815709, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
05-08 19:25:10.990 10937-10937/com.example.denny.protoype2 W/GmsSupportLifecycleFrag: Unresolved error while connecting client. Stopping auto-manage.
05-08 19:25:11.114 10937-10968/com.example.denny.protoype2 W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
05-08 19:25:11.114 10937-10968/com.example.denny.protoype2 W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7fc8fab76680, error=EGL_SUCCESS
05-08 19:25:15.145 10937-10968/com.example.denny.protoype2 E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7fc8f104e1f0
```

This is the relevant class's onCreate():

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_viewing_window);
        mRequestingLocationUpdates = ((Protoype2)getApplication()).getRequestingLocationUpdates();
        if (mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            StoppedMessage();
        }
        ExceedInstance = 0;
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .build();
        String[] LocationPermission = new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ViewingWindow.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(ViewingWindow.this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                GPSExplanation();
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ViewingWindow.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
            }

        }
        onRequestPermissionsResult(MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, LocationPermission, grantResults);

        final Button BackButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.VWBackButton);
        BackButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent GoBackIntent = new Intent (ViewingWindow.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(GoBackIntent);
            }
        });
        updateValuesFromBundle(savedInstanceState);

    }
```

Comment: Can you access the internet at all on the AVD? E.g. via the browser?

Comment: I can. The browser works perfectly fine. The app however... is a different story.

Comment: Have you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37115338/trouble-connecting-to-googleplayservices-on-avd